# how to change the key of validation error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am new to laravel and working on apis, I have made an api in which i have implemented validation.Everything is working fine but i am stuck on a little thing. I want to to change the key name in the validation error. For example For the "unique" validation error. This is what now showing

[image]

I want to rename "email"(text) key with "message"(text)

I have tried so many thing in illuminate/support/validation.php

messagebag.php file but if it changes then error show of "data undefined".

The links i followed are

https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/21/laravel-5-message-bags-adding-messages-to-the-message-bag-with-add

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-validation-message-for-array-using-different-key?page=0

[Override laravel validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823513/override-laravel-validation-message)

This is the validation code

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'first_name' => 'required',
      'last_name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'fcm_token' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required',  
      'c_password' => 'required|same:password' 
    ]);
```

Comment: You should add atleast one of your tried code so, people could help you on that code, your question seems to asking people guess about your codes and setup, and write you full codes.

Comment: Why exactly do you "need" this? It's not going to work if you have more than 1 field being validated.

Comment: @Qirel i want to rename the key in the response. I dont want to validate two fields.

Comment: @Dilek please let me know if you are not clear about my question. I am not asking for any script. I am asking about the way to do it. I tried the same code in same files that are mentioned and also given in the provided links.

I want to rename "email"(text) key with "message"(text)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose though, the index is the name of the invalid field -- why would you need to change it? My point is that, should there at one point become more than 1 field, you won't be able to separate which message belongs to which field.

Comment: @Qirel i want to show one mssage at a time. So dont worry about it.

Comment: It is definitely doable, can you show the validation code?

Comment: @Viney added the code at the end of the question, please check.

Comment: Are you using some code for extracting the error messages? I see `status there

Comment: @Viney yes. you are right. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually loop over the error MessageBag and construct the response to replace a key

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'first_name' => 'required',
      'last_name'  => 'required',
      'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'fcm_token'  => 'required',
      'password'   => 'required',  
      'c_password' => 'required|same:password' 
    ]);   

    $errors = [];
    foreach ($validator->errors()->messages() as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'email')
            $key = 'message';
        $errors[$key] = is_array($value) ? implode(',', $value) : $value;
        //implode is for when you have multiple errors for a same key
        //like email should valid as well as unique
    }

    $result = array("status" => count($errors)?0:1, 'data'=>$errors);
    return $result;
```

Comment: when email field is empty then the program does not reach to the method. It directly shows from validation exception.I already tried this.

Comment: oh that means the validation is running somewhere else but it's hard to guess where with the information available

Answer (score 0):

In resources - lang - en (Or Any Langauge) - validation.php

Put This code in bottom:

```
'attributes' => [
    'email' => 'The Email', 
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the key of the error message of a certain field, you can transfer the validation of this particular field from the request to the controller (or service). This way you can throw an error with any name you want.

For example:

```
if (#your validation of the field failed#) {
  throw ValidationException::withMessages(['your_key' => 'your message']);
}
```

And don't forget this line:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

The error now will look like this:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "your_key": [
            "your message"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if I understand the problem well. This will help you:

[a https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique)

In your case:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,message'
```

unique:table,column,except,idColumn

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

In Laravel, you can try and validate your email this way:

```
'email'=>'required|email'
```

Comment: "_I want to replace "email" key with "message"_" How does this change `email` to `message`?

Comment: @kerbholz edited question 

I want to rename "email"(text) key with "message"(text)

Comment: @dev: I know, that's what I was saying. Netwons code does nothing related to this

Comment: @kerbholz yes, do you have any idea?