# How to custom response JSON object validator

Tags: laravel, validation

i have problem with response validator like this :

```
{
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ]
}
```

im want to like this :

```
{
    "email": 
        "The email field is required."
    ,
    "password": 
        "The password field is required." 
}
```

this my validator

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
```

everyone can help me ? thanks very much

Comment: Easiest way is to define your custom method to translate the return value of `$validator->errors()` into the format you want.

Comment: Every field has an array of messages because they can contain multiple error messages (e.g. when multiple rules fail for a field). Anyway, you can always override validator class to modify message rules - [somewhat like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823513/override-laravel-validation-message).